# Moore-Penrose inverse error approximation for matrix product

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Given two matrices $A \in \mathbb{R^{m \times k}}, B \in \mathbb{R^{n \times k}}$ with $k> m > n$, I want to compute $(A B^{\dagger})^{\dagger} A$ where $\cdot^{\dagger}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse. If it were true that $(A B^{\dagger})^{\dagger} A = B A^{\dagger} A$ (which I know is not in my case), I could crucially accelerate an algorithm of mine (because $B$ changes with each iteration but $A$ is fixed, so $A^{\dagger} A$ could be precomputed).

I was wondering, if there exists a good approximation of the error $(A B^{\dagger})^{\dagger} A - B A^{\dagger} A$ that does not rely on computing $B^{\dagger}$. Or alternatively, if there exists a good approximation of $(A B^{\dagger})^{\dagger} A$ without computing $B^{\dagger}$.

Such an approximation might not exist and maybe my question is complete nonsense but I thought, maybe you have some ideas! Thanks.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ arbitrary matrices? Or are the related in some way?

Comment: @Deane Arbitrary and unrelated but of full row rank, each

Comment: I know nothing about computational linear algebra and haven't worked out any details, but couldn't you change bases in both domain and range so that $$A = \begin{bmatrix} I_{m\times m} & 0_{m\times(k-m)}\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: For a base change, I’ll have to compute an inverse anyway, don’t I? That won’t enable me to overcome the computation of a Pseudoinverse :(

Comment: You only need to find the change of basis matrix for $A$. It appears to me that during the iteration, you don't need to recompute any inverse matrix. You just need to do an extra matrix multiplication or two.